# Question on Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: lebesgue-measure

The question is as follows :

Show that for any set $A$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there is an open set $O$ containing $A$ and such that $m^*(O) \le m^*(A)+ \epsilon$.

Solution given in the book is as follows :

Choose a sequence of intervals $I_n$ such that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n$ and

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty l(I_n)-\epsilon/2 \le m^*(A)$.

If $I_n$=$[a_n,b_n)$, let $I_n' = (a-\epsilon/2^{n+1},b_n)$, so that ,

$A \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n'$.

Hence if $O =\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n'$, $O$ is an open set and

$m^*(O) \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty l(I_n') = \sum_{n=0}^\infty l(I_n)+\epsilon/2 \le m^*(A)+\epsilon$

There are a few things that i didn't quite follow in the solution given :

First, why has $I_n$ been chosen as $[a_n,b_n)$ particularly ? Can't i just let $I_n$ to be a sequence of open intervals and choose $O$ as the union of all $I_n$'s ?

Second,how is $I_n'$ being formulated ? why particularly $a-\epsilon/2^{n+1}$ ? How would one get to that ?

Comment: @copper.hat Alright i will do that but otherwise example 2 is on page 29.

Comment: @copper.hat I have edited the question.

Comment: The author of the book defines the outer measure in terms of intervals of the form $[a,b)$ which is where that comes from (see the first paragraph is Section 2.1). To convert these half-open intervals into open intervals, we add a 'small' bit on the left. You need to ensure that the **sum** of the lengths that you add remain less than some $\epsilon$, hence the $\epsilon {1 \over 2^{n+1}}$.